# Обязательны ли Фреймворки в C# для проектирования?

Tags: c#, mvvm, framework, mvvm-light

Можно создавать MVVM программы на C# без использования таких фреймворков например как MVVM Light Toolkit? И очень ли сложно будет без них обойтись?

Comment: да, можно создавать

Comment: вам придется написать много вспомогательного кода, который и будет самопальным фремворком )

Comment: в любом языке можно пользоваться фреймворками или компонентами (либами), как вам лучше

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVVM - это только паттерн проектирования, а значит если вы понимаете паттерн, то есть у вас готовый фреймворк или нет не имеет значения.

В основном, необходимость использовать фреймворки и библиотеки исходит из масштаба проекта, решаемых задач, существующей кодовой базы и предпочтений тимлидов. Если проект большой и не использовались сторонние разработки, то большая часть вашей кодовой базы и будет тем самым фреймворком.

А теперь более важные вопросы: Насколько большой проект? Сколько человек над ним работает? Насколько хорошо документирован ваш код? Сколько времени понадобится новому разработчику чтобы изучить и начать эффективно его использовать? В случае распространенных фреймворков эти вопросы стоят не так остро, т.к. в каком-то виде документация обычно есть, иногда есть техподдержка производителя, в сети достаточно решений типичных проблем на тематических форумах, EnSO и тут.

Для небольшого проекта острой необходимости в тяжелых фреймворках нет, более того, за счет отсутствия тяжелых и неповоротливых "монстров" небольшой проект даже выиграет, если не надумает расти конечно. В случае большого проекта все не так однозначно.

И да, это касается не только упомянутого вами MVVM, но и всех остальных областей, будь то WEB, работа с базами данных и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

Фреймворки не обязательны.

Я вот обхожусь, острой необходимости в использовании фреймворка пока что не возникало. Мелкие удобства вполне делаются вручную.

Comment: Понятно, а в чём удобства этих фреймворков, что они упрощают? По идее фреймворк должен ускорять процесс работы и делать всё проще.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Я ими почти не пользуюсь, так что особо много подсказать не могу. Например, фреймворк может содержать базовый класс для VM. Или реализацию `ICommand`. Или `WeakEventManager`. Но всё это несложно реализовать и вручную при необходимости.